# What does units on first value accomplish when using "flex" shorthand?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Documentation about the flex shorthand on MDN say:

> One-value syntax: the value must be one of:
>
> ```
> a unitless <number>: then it is interpreted as <flex-grow>.
> a valid value for width: then it is interpreted as <flex-basis>.
> one of the keyword values none, auto, or initial.
> ```
>
> Two-value syntax: the first value must be a unitless  and it
>   is interpreted as . The second value must be one of:
>
> ```
> a unitless <number>: then it is interpreted as <flex-shrink>.
> a valid value for width: then it is interpreted as <flex-basis>.
> ```
>
> Three-value syntax:
>
> ```
> the first value must be a unitless <number> and it is interpreted as <flex-grow>.
> the second value must be a unitless <number> and it is interpreted as <flex-shrink>.
> the third value must be a valid value for width and is interpreted as <flex-basis>.
> ```

But I've seen in many places this shorthand being used like:

```
flex: 30% 0 0;
```

I can see and edit this values on the web inspector, and see that they render different values in the browser; but not entirly clear exactly what effect does it have.

Since it's a three value syntax, the first value should be interpreted as `flex-grow`, but that property expects a unitless number.

How is a percentage applied in a case like this? And is this defined somewhere?

Comment: It seems that (in Chrome at least) if the first value of `flex` is a `width`, it is interpreted as the `flex-basis` and the 2nd as `flex-grow` and 3rd (if included) as `flex-shrink`. However, I can't find this behaviour documented anywhere.

Comment: @ksav: It's in the property's grammar. Not the most obvious place to look, granted, but it's there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shorthand

```
flex: 30% 0 0;
```

is equivalent to

```
flex: 0 0 30%;
```

where the first 0 is <flex-grow>, the second 0 is <flex-shrink>, and the 30% is <flex-basis>. As long as each of the three component values corresponds 1:1 to a unique longhand property, it doesn't matter what order values with different units appear in. Of course, given two unitless values, the first always corresponds to <flex-grow> and the second to <flex-shrink>.

This is documented in the grammar of the `flex` shorthand:

> none | [ <‘flex-grow’> <‘flex-shrink’>? || <‘flex-basis’> ]

The || "separates two or more options: one or more of them must occur, in any order", as documented in [css-values-3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#component-combinators).